# How to read json file which has multiple json objects seperated by new line?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to read a json file in which each line contains a new json object.

File looks like below -

```
{'P':'a1','D':'b1','T':'c1'}
{'P':'a2','D':'b2','T':'c2'}
{'P':'a3','D':'b3','T':'c3'}
{'P':'a4','D':'b4','T':'c4'}
```

I'm trying to read this file like below -

```
print pd.read_json("sample.json", lines = True)
```

I'm facing below exception -

```
ValueError: Expected object or value
```

Actually this sample.json file is of ~240mb. Format of this file is like this only. It's each line contains one new json object and I want to read this file using **python pandas**.

Comment: Yes, now tested - need double quotes, because single quotes are not valid JSON

Comment: Also technically the extension for this file should be `.jsonl`.

Comment: In which conditions program throws "ValueError: Expected object or value" this error?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, it's not really JSON. You can use `ast.literal_eval()`:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

with open('sample.json') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(line) for line in content])
```

Or replace the single quotes with doubles:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('sample.json') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

pd.DataFrame([json.loads(line.replace("'", '"')) for line in content])
```